# Windows Store App/Metro on closed/suspend event does not work

Tags: events, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, exit

I have this game I'm making which involves two online players. If one quits the application, the other should be notified. I'm using the onsuspend event but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Application.Current.Suspending += Current_Suspending;
        // and a bunch of other stuff
    }

    private async void Current_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        await game.leaveGame();
    }
```

Any help would be strongly appreciated. I am 100% sure the game.leaveGame() function works -- I've tested it.

Comment: You will have to make this work without the *async* keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you return from suspending event application is suspended, so in your case async method game.leaveGame() won't finish. 
Try to change  your code to (assuming game.leaveGame is sync method):

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Application.Current.Suspending += Current_Suspending;
    // and a bunch of other stuff
}

private void Current_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    game.leaveGame();
}
```

For more details about application lifecycle [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx).